# Yeoman - V5 is not a function?

Tags: angularjs, function, typeerror, yeoman

Hi I have just followed this tutorial [link](http://yeoman.io/codelab/) step by step, I am making an angular App, it works fine, but i am getting this error in console `V5 is not a function` Although the app works fine. I am attaching the exact steps which i took and also a screen shot of my console.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to install npm and nodejs again with bower, make sure you have the compatible versions with your application.